# Datatable too slow to load

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee, datatable, datatables

here is my html Code

```
<table border=1 id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>title1</th>
                <th>title2</th>
                <th>title3</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%                      
            String resultat = "select * from table where 1;//for example
                }
                try {

                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(resultat);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        %>


            <tr>
                <td><%=rs.getString("col1")%></td>
                <td style="white-space: pre-line"><%=rs.getString("col2")%></td>
                <td><%=rs.getString("col3")%></td>

            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </tbody>
```

but when i load the page with huge rows +50000 records , it takes more than 30sec to load the datatable, and I want to load per page for example if the 10 first row are loaded then the datatable will be ready to be shown and the rest is loading in the backend tl complete all the rows.

here the code of Datatable :

```
var table =$('#example').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            { "width": "16%","className": "dt-body-left"},/*css ta3 La premiere colonne*/
            { "width": "65%"},
            {"width": "19%","className": "dt-body-center"},

          ],
          "language": {
              "info":  "<b>Resultat :</b> _TOTAL_ ligne(s) <br/><br/>Affichage de _START_ à _END_ lignes  ",
              "infoEmpty":"<p id='zero'> <b>0</b> Found!! </p>",
            },
        fixedHeader: true,
        searching : true,
        deferRender: true,
        paging : true,
        bProcessing : true,
        dom : 'iBftlrp'
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the question? If you have many rows you should look at `serverSide` processing.

Comment: @davidkonrad my question is how to load only 10 rows to manipulate the datatable while the loading of the rest of records ?